# GridView - Fire SelectionChanged event on an already selected item

Tags: xaml, gridview, mvvm, mvvm-light, selectionchanged

In my Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1 App, I have a GridView and I want to change my VisualState after an item is selected. I can do this easy with behavior like this :

```
 <GridView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="NextVisualState"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid Width="80" Height="80">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="150"></ItemsWrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
```

The problem occur when my item is already selected (The user can be on this VisualState with the Item already selected by binding or something), I want the SelectionChanged event to be fired if the user click on an item that already selected (so he can go to the next VisualState).

I try to change the VisualState on the ItemClick event but the event is fired before the item is selected so it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your Gridview control
2. Change selected Index property from 0 to -1

I'm not sure whether it works or not, but you can try.

Comment: Thx Dipak, but if I do this, I loose the selectedItem. And this is not what I want. I want the user to be able to click on an already selected item.

Comment: Then use flag variable on selectionChanged event.. like if flag==0 { flag = 1 Your action code } it will not run your action code on load event

Comment: SelectionChanged is an event that will actually 'only' fire when 'the selection is changed' so you can't use that if you don't want to manipulate teh selected index yourself. A possible solution is using the Tapped event. Because that will always fire when tapping an item...

Comment: @Dipak : But the problem is that selectionChanged event is not firing when clicking on an already selectedItem...
So anyway w/o the flag, my action won't happen if the user click an already selectedItem.

Comment: Thx Depechie, but Tapped Happeb when you click outside any Items of the GridView

Comment: Ok i put the Tapped event to be bound on each item in the GridView rather than on the GridView itself and it's working now, thx Depechie

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Collections}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="MyGridView">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="80" Height="80" Background="Transparent">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                            <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangeStateCommand, ElementName=MyGridView}" CommandParameter="NextState"></Core:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="150"></ItemsWrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
```

I had to set a background in the Grid Datatemplate to make the whole Grid clickable I don't know why.